# "Поднатореть" и "понатореть" — в чём разница?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов

Слышал лишь *поднатореть,* а только что встретилось *понатореть.* Есть ли разница и в чём она?

Comment: Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 2):

Разница в ситуациях, когда употребляются эти слова. В обоих случаях это приобретение некоторого опыта, но в слове ***поднатореть*** чувствуется **результативность**, а слове ***понатореть*** ― **временнАя** характеристика процесса.

1) ***Поднатореть*** ― приобрести **некоторый положительный опыт** в чем-либо.

Приставка ПОД со значением **в ограниченных размерах.**

Политические новобранцы должны поднатореть **в искусстве политического диалога**.  Алексей успел **изрядно** **поднатореть в криминальной терминологии.**

2) ***Понатореть*** ― **некоторое время** практиковаться в чем-либо. **В длинные годы** эмиграции он **понаторел** на ресторанном деле. Клюев, по-видимому, уже  **понаторел** в хождении по писательским кружкам и гостиным: он успел выработать нарочитую манеру держаться степенно...

Приставка ПО с **временным** значением.

Comment: *но в слове поднатореть чувствуется результативность, а слове понатореть ― временнАя характеристика процесса* - Ой... Вот уж чего в "поднатореть" нету - это результативности. Скорее наоборот. Да и со "временной  характеристикой" - понатореть тож как-то не очень стыкуется... У "по" есть семантика повторяемости действия (с глаголами движения в основном), это весьма далеко от каких-то "временных" аспектов. Но тут даже такая повторяемость не проходит, значение иное...

Comment: Что я могу сказать... Чувствуют люди по-разному, а значения приставок проверены по словарю.  Понатореть - заниматься каким-то делом некоторое время и, возможно, приобрести опыт. Поднатореть - это просто приобрести опыт, время не указывается. Нет у приставки ПОД значения времени, а у приставки ПО такое значение есть.

Answer (score 0):

"Понатореть" как раз более универсальный, традиционный и общелитературный вариант.

Разницы-то большой нету, во всяком случае словари её явно не обозначают. Тут, думается, другое... Приставка "по" в данном значении (поделать что-то недолго или добившись только частичного результата) теряет продуктивность в пользу "под". Хотя исходно-то они не полностью синонимичны ("под" в таком значении придает смягчительно-эмоциональную окраску). Но у "по" и без очень много всяких значений - и язык стремиться эту систему упростить.

Отсюда пары типа *поистратиться - подыстратиться*, *полечить - подлечить*, *поранить - подранить* и другие. Первый член каждой такой такой пары - классический и нейтральный, второй - более современный и эмоциональный. То есть дело скорее в акцентах и стилистической принадлежности.

В тех же случаях, когда значение у глагола с этими приставками достаточно разное, сближения не происходит (поработать - подработать, поесть-подъесть - здесь просматриваются другие значения приставок).

Comment: В словарях Ушакова и Ожегова различие указывается ("поднаторел - немного наторел"). В современной речи встречается почти исключительно "поднаторел", отсюда и вопрос возник.

Comment: @Alex_ander "поднаторел - немного наторел" - У Ожегова "понаторел" вообще нету. А У ушакова - "Немного или постепенно натореть".  Какое ***различие***?!

Comment: Это я по невнимательности. У Ушакова оба есть, причем "понатореть"  с пометкой "прост". Если у Ожегова только "под-", то это лишнее подтверждение забытости другого варианта. Склоняюсь к логичности приводимых Sharon соображений: "понатореть" ближе по характеру действия к "поделать какое-то время", чем к _результату_, к которому "немного" приближает (подводит) "под-".